# Flask send_from_directory

Tags: file-upload, flask, download

I have a Flask web app that allows users to upload files and then download or display them in a browser. Should I be using `send_from_directory` to serve these files from the upload folder on my server when in production?

Comment: It all depends on your use case - if you need to validate that the user is allowed to access the files, then yes, you will want to use `send_from_directory`.  If anyone is supposed to be able to access them, then I would simply let the proxy server serve the contents of the `upload` directory.

Comment: Thanks, are there any significant disadvantages to doing so? I'd rather use send_from_directory than server filepaths with document id's to be safe since the uploaded files are user-specific.

Comment: `send_from_directory` is *potentially* slower (since it has to go through another layer of routing).  If you need authentication though, keeping it all centralized in your application is probably the easiest way to go (the difference isn't going to be significant unless you are serving a *lot* of files).

Comment: @SeanVieira Note that `send_from_directory()` does not magically guess  Vary headers, and it sets `Cache-Control: public, ...`.  Therefore if you use `send_from_directory()` to send authenticated files, you may need to set some additional option.  At least if you use unencrypted HTTP, which allows for caching proxies.

Comment: Good point - `send_from_directory` returns a `Response`, so you can set headers on that if you `response = send_from_directory(...); response.headers['Cache-Control']`

Answer (score 0):

You are better off letting nginx serve your static files.  It is well known that flask is relatively poor performance for this task. However, if your server is not going to be fully utilized it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

i have accomplished that kind of idea. im using flask-rest. But u can use this as reference. 
**For uploading file**

`from document_folder.config import dir_path
            file = data['file'] #data is a reqparse.
            filename = werkzeug.secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(str(dir_path), str(filename))`

**config.py for document static folder. place this in the document static folder**

`import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

**for downloading**
You must save the document's name to your db so you can download the documents.

`docu = DocumentModel.exists(_id)
        if docu:
            filename = docu.filename
            return send_file(os.path.join(dir_path, filename), as_attachment=True)`

The parser should be like this.

`parser.add_argument('file',
        type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage,
        location='files'
        )`