# python flask file upload fails silently

Tags: python, file, flask, request

I'm running a flask server on port `3000` that accepts POST requests at the endpoint `:3000/upload`. However, the file upload portion does not work.

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def post_upload():
    print ("test")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print ("test2")
        zfile = request.files['file']
        if zfile:
            print("test3")
            filename = secure_filename(zfile.filename)
            zfile.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
            return "success"
        else:
            print ("test4")
            return "fail"
    return 'blah'
```

I am sending a POST with form-data `key` is equal to `file` and `value` is a PNG image. The response the client gets is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

The printout on the server is:

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:3000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
test
test2
104.148.224.253 - - [05/Aug/2017 19:30:04] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Why is it failing silently after `zfile = request.files['file']`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using flask's recommended format for file uploads for better error checking. I'm guessing that 'file' doesn't exist in the dictionary, so it faults when checking for value. 'file' should be replaced with the name of the file input element, thus if you have <input type=file name=file2>, then then it should be request.files['file2'].

From http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/:

```
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                filename=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
```

Comment: I tried this first. I get an output that says `No file part`. I am using POSTMAN with a form where `key`=`file` and `value` is a PNG image.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had some headers left over from a previous POSTMAN request that were screwing up the results. I removed them and it worked. The headers were

```
Authorization:Basic ...
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I'm guessing the `Content-Type` header screwed up the form encoding, but I'm not sure how or why, because it fails silently.

Answer (score 0):

There is the same question from one article. You can use this as reference. I'm using flask-rest API. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45540179/6689146)

The parser should be like this.

```
parser.add_argument('file',
        type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage,
        location='files'
        )
```